# partial s3 bucket migration while upgrading from alfresco 4.2.2 to 5.1.1

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

We are migrating from alfresco 4.2.2 to 5.1.1.we have 60 TB of data in S3 prod bucket(4.2.2).Can we do the partial migration(10 TB)[clone] out of 60 TB data to the new bucket(5.1.1-bucket) so that we can point from 511 server.we don't want to clone the entire 60 TB of data to the new bucket.we want to clone only partial data(10TB) to the new bucket.

Comment: Whether you use Community or Alfresco One?

Comment: alfresco one enterprise